# Expresso Store 2.5.1 (EE2) checkout/tax query

Tags: expresso-store, checkout, tax

Is it possible to show prices inclusive of tax at checkout with this version of Store?

At present, there doesn't seem to be any tags to show inclusive prices in the basket/checkout and if we try to apply these via a plugin (mulitplying via the tax rate) the calculations are out, I guess by the rounding that is taking place after tax is applied.

For example, client wants to show the following:

Items listing unit price inc tax, quantity and total line price inc tax (before discount)
Subtotal of basket inclusive of tax 
Discount as applies to subtotal
Total after discount
Shipping costs
Total after shipping

Anybody know if the above is at all possible?

Cole

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the variable options listed here: https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/checkout_tag.html#order_details

That probably has what you need!